# Can I include an Excel file as a resource in my Jar file which can be edited at runtime?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am using ApachePoi to edit the excel sheet. My program currently works, but I have had to define an absolute path to the spreadsheet on my computer. This program is being implemented by another framwork int the architecture (which has nothing to do with me) so I cannot define an absolute path to the excel sheet.

Ideally, I want to include the Excel spreadsheet in my Jar file resources and have the spreadsheet edited at runtime by the program.

Is there anyway for me to do this?

Comment: Bundle it in the jar, then load it as a classpath resource?

Comment: `getClass().getResourceAsStream(<template_path>)`. "template_path" has format like "/template/filename.xlsx". "template" is a sub folder of `src/main/resources`